# How to add a header line to a downloaded file

Tags: abap

How do I add column names upon downloading it into text file. I can already download a file but there is no column names inside my text file.

I am using GUI_DOWNLOAD call method function.

Comment: Use Google! There is actually a nice example [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/message/6048823#6048823).

Comment: Please add the code to reproduce your issue. Also mention why it should add automatically "column names", and where should it take these names from.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new internal table with all fields are CHAR type. Append header texts to the first row and append your data containing internal table to it.